# Input string was not in a correct format - trying to insert string value to int typed datagridview cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, telerik, radgridview

I'm trying to fill in a **telerik radDataGridView** (the same problem happens with a normal *dataGridView* as well).

one of the columns in my db table is named [*updateType*].

the *'type'* is described in an enum:

```cs
public enum TypeEnum
{
    INSERT = 0,
    UPDATE_OR_INSERT = 1,
    UPDATE = 2,
    DELETE_OR_INSERT = 3
};
```

i'm filling the dataGridView *(dgv)* in the Load event:

```cs
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.table1TableAdapter.Fill(this.tempdbDataSet.Table1);

  for (int i = 0; i < dgv.RowCount; i++)
  {
    switch ((int)dgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value)
    {
      case (int)TypeEnum.INSERT:
            dgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = "INSERT";
            break;
      case (int)TypeEnum.UPDATE_OR_INSERT:
            dgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = "UPDATE/INSERT";
            break;
      case (int)TypeEnum.UPDATE:
            dgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = "UPDATE";
            break;
      case (int)TypeEnum.DELETE_OR_INSERT:
            dgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = "INSERT/DELETE";
            break;
      default:
            break;
    }
  }
}
```

but it fails, when trying to fill in a *string* value to an *int* typed gridview cell,

throwing an exception  **Input string was not in a correct format**.

thanks to anyone who can solve this.

Comment: On which line exactly?

Comment: check this line: switch ((int)dgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value). It seems that value fetch from database is not an int type.

Comment: I don't get it.  You have a column that you _know_ to be of `int` type, and then you try to stuff a `string` value into it and don't understand why it doesn't like that?

Comment: If Telerik's control is worth its salt, it will support a column display aliasing function, whereby you can set the cell value to one thing, but set a different corresponding display value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem in a different way.
instead of filling the datagridview with a table adapter, 
i've built it step by step.
for example:

//---

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        dgv.Rows.Add(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString(),
                     dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString(),
                     GetEnumString((int)dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[2]));
```

//---

```
private string GetEnumString(int n)
{
   switch (n)
   {
      case (int)TypeEnum.INSERT:
           return "INSERT";
      case (int)TypeEnum.UPDATE:
           return "UPDATE";
      case (int)TypeEnum.UPDATE_OR_INSERT:
           return "UPDATE/INSERT";
      case (int)TypeEnum.DELETE_OR_INSERT:
           return "INSERT/DELETE";
      default: return "";
      }
   }
}

public enum TableUpdateModeEnum
{
   INSERT = 0,
   UPDATE_OR_INSERT = 1,
   UPDATE = 2,
   DELETE_OR_INSERT = 3
};
```

thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
switch ((int)dgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value)
{
  case (int)TableUpdateModeEnum.INSERT:
        dgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = (int)TypeEnum.INSERT;
        break;
...
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but my intention is to display the ".ToString()" value of the enum, not converting it to another int

Comment: What is the type of your column in which you want to place this string data?

Comment: it doesn't matters - i've tried to set it as int, or nvarchar,
the problem still remains.